# Global variables in Helm - Why are they recommended so often

Tags: kubernetes-helm

In programming languages global variables were one of the first options to share state among several components. However, by now most modern languages seem to try and limit their usage and as a programmer you typically seem to learn to only use them sparingly (note: global variables seem (mostly) shunned, global constants just regarded as having a very limited purpose, one can view helm global values in that context as being more on the side of global constants in purpose).
On the other hand in helm templates they are a prominent option that is often mentioned in tutorials but I haven't seen any advice to be cautious with using them.

Personally I see no benefit in having charts that rely on global variables over using yaml references in the values files when the same value is needed by multiple charts. Using global variables especially for library charts just makes it intransparent which charts actually use that value without looking through all the subcharts whereas with yaml references it is directly clear by looking at the values file they are used in.
The same way this limits the possibility to change the meaning of a global variable if you want to adjust a subchart because other charts might rely on the existing definition of the value.

My current view on the main aspects of both options
global values:

- allow sharing the same value across multiple charts that you or someone else maintains having to set it only once in the values file of a parent chart
- require each chart that uses them to agree on the definition
- changing the global value to affect one (sub) chart can have unforeseen consequences to other subcharts
- split the places where values affecting the same subchart are placed
- allow "enforcing" the same value in multiple charts
- BUT can conflict with other charts and other charts can start using the same global value out of convenience although not strictly requiring the same values all the time

yaml references:

- allow sharing the same value across multiple charts that you or someone else maintains having to set the value only once in the values file of a parent chart but requiring to place the reference for each subchart in addition
- definitions of the values for individual charts are independent
- changing the value for a single subchart is straight forward and isolated from effects to other subcharts
- all values affecting one subchart are in the same place (at the least there is reference one can follow to find the original definition)
- allow using the same value for multiple charts, but indeed an author of multiple charts cannot enforce a parent chart to use the same values for an attribute used in two different charts
- charts are isolated from each other

**Are there any aspects on global values that I overlook or good use-cases for them? Especially in the comparison towards yaml references - but also in general? Am I overlooking use-cases different from mine where they make more sense?**

My use case is that we maintain a few library charts (a handful), some are representing our own deployments, some wrap around external tooling we want to deploy into the cluster, and we may use some provided by externals. All in all a single parent chart typically has less than 10 subcharts to deal with. The values they would share at the moment are labels and parts of their names which we could do as global values or yaml references.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confusing global *variables* with Helm's special handling of an input field named `global`.  The Go `text/template` language has fairly simple scoping rules and does not support global variables; other things in many programming languages can have a global namespace (constants, procedures, types) and this is not controversial or problematic.

If you don't like `.Values.global` and YAML anchors can meet your needs, absolutely feel free to structure your charts this way.

The one obvious problem with YAML anchors is that they're local to a file.  You can deploy a Helm chart with multiple values files, so if you have a file of environment-specific settings that can't refer to an anchor definition in the default values file.  A second obvious problem is that you'll have to list out the same subcharts everywhere, and make sure you list all of them

```yaml
# values.dev.yaml
labels: &labels { ... }

first: { labels: *labels }
second: { labels: *labels }
# oops
fourth: { labels: *labels }
```

`.Values.global` becomes a little less fraught if you use a *library chart* to provide template definitions that reference it.  The [Bitnami charts library](https://github.com/bitnami/charts) has a good example of this: the charts there generally depend on [`bitnami/common`](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/common) as a dependency, which includes some specific things that use `.Values.global` in specific ways; [for example](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/main/bitnami/common/templates/_images.tpl)

```
{{- define "common.images.image" -}}
...
{{- if .global }}
    {{- if .global.imageRegistry }}
     {{- $registryName = .global.imageRegistry -}}
    {{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
...
{{- end -}}
```

Now for *all* of the Bitnami charts, and anything else that includes `bitnami/common` as a dependency and includes a call to `include "common.images.image"`, you can define a set of values

```yaml
# values.dev.yaml
global:
  # avoid Docker Hub request rate limits
  registry: docker-mirror.example.com
```

Your deployment system might even have this fragment as its own YAML file and inject it with a `helm install -f` option alongside the per-environment settings.  That's trickier to do with YAML anchors.

In either case, also note that you are depending on charts interpreting values with the same name in the same way.  If you have some charts that expect `labels` to be a dictionary and some a preformatted string, you can't share values either way.  This inconsistency is more of a problem with `.Values.global`, to be sure, but you can't solve it with YAML anchors either.

Comment: Okay that seems to confirm my current take that the yaml references are fine for simple cases (and imho superior there) but for some you simply need to use this mechanism as that's what helm provides and there is no easy other way. I guess what I miss in this handling is some sort of namespacing that makes it possible, convenient and guides you towards grouping global values and also restricts then their accessibility. Currently it feels to me bit like an ad-hoc hack that opens a wild west of values used by different charts (possibly ending up in naming conflicts etc.)

Comment: But thanks. I'll wait a bit in case someone else drops in but otherwise will accept. As a minor improvement suggestion: I needed to read the `second ...#ooops ...fourth` example a couple of times until I got the #oops was referencing a missing third entry and was not pointing out some mistake with the fourth entry below it. Perhaps you can make that clearer by changing to #oops forgot the third one